# Make the same header and footer in HTML pages, when they are displaced in different folders - images gone

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following the threads and advice here:

Make header and footer files to be included in multiple html pages https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-include-a-header-and-footer-file-in-every-HTML-page-we-are-designing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDFxEALe0JA&ab_channel=JoseMartinez

I've managed with setting one header and footer for all the HTML websites I have got.

The problem is, that I have some images in my header, which don't come through, when I place some HTML site in the different folder, for example:

In the main folder: **Online Survey Form** I have the following HTML files

```
header
footer
index
closedpoor
```

I use the images for my header, which are located in the images folder.

But I also have the folder, where I placed some specific HTML websites. The folder is called: **Survey_forms**, where I have some files:

```
closedpoor_survey_form.html
```

For this file my JQuery function looks as this:

```
   <script>  
    $(function(){ 
      $("#header").load("../header.html");  
      $("#footer").load("../footer.html");  
    }); 
  </script>
```

whereas the image link in header.html file look like this:

```
  <img src="images/logo.png" height="60px">
```

I don't know why my header image is gone on the HTML site located in a different folder

[image]

Comment: Replace `"images/logo.png"` with `"/images/logo.png"`

Comment: Aaaa I see now! Silly mistake. Many thanks for this mate :)

Comment: Replace $("#header").load(".../header.html");   with $("#header").load("../header.html");  , only two dots

Comment: @Grumpy thnaks, I have to alter this question. I had a good path in my code, but I have made mistake here.